# Flow to Typescript conversion

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, flowtype

I have started building a web app using ReactJS and Flow in Visual Studio Code.
At the beginning when my code base was small, the [Flow plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode) in Visual Studio Code was working as expected. Errors were highlighted etc.
However, the larger my code base became, the more problems I had with Flow. Although the plugin was still running (it is visible in the VS Code status bar at the bottom), it just stopped analyzing my code. Now, it reached a point where it does not do anything anymore.

I was wondering whether there is a Flow to TypeScript conversion tool as I really can't find a solution for my Flow/VSCode setup. 
If the majority of the code can be transformed/converted to Typescript in a automated fashion, I would be willing to give it a try.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/bcherny/flow-to-typescript. Also most of the types should be compatible as is, just change the files extensions from _js_ to _ts_

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL. Unfortunately it does not install properly on my Win10 machine. NPM install does not fail, but the content of the module directory contains only a package.json file.
but you're hit was very good. I found another one here https://github.com/Kiikurage/babel-plugin-flow-to-typescript. However, it does not work properly or in other words, many Flow features are not recognized.
It seems I will have to rewrite it if I really want to switch to TS.

Comment: If you're working on windows - you can't really use flow.. It will keep crashing every time you change some source files

Comment: @dm88 You don't even need to "rewrite". Since most of the type declarations carry, you can just rename your .js to .ts and then go fixing errors like replacing `type` declarations with `interface` (if you wish), replacing Flow's `:` cast with TS's `as`, removing the `@flow` header, removing `if` checks that only exist to keep Flow happy, etc. And your React components might need additional touches depending on how you created them. But overall it's just search and replacing.

Comment: I managed to get Flow working for a bit and I saw that roughly 80 errors have been detected. Given that, I might be quicker moving the code to TS as @zeh suggested rather than trying to fix Flow issues.

Comment: I'm biased, but that makes sense. Flow just runs terribly not just on Windows but also on macOS. The "service" stops working all the time and at some point even the command line starts failing, forcing you to run a separate Flow server on a dedicated terminal window. It's a lot of hassle.